# How to test applications and websites with less computing power?

Tags: testing, emulation

Currently I develop on an extremely powerful machine: Pentium i7, 32 GB Ram, SSD, 1 Gb 1028-bit graphics card, etc.

What I'm trying to figure out is the proper way to test my applications and web pages simulating a less powerful computer. Is there any way to simulate a slower processor, less ram, slower hard drive, and weaker graphics card? I'm not sure if I missed anything else in terms of what else to simulate...

The only thing I've figured out so far is resolution, but that was as easy as changing my monitor resolution. Though, if there is a way to simulate less resolution without needing to change my actual screen resolution as well, that'd be great.

Answer (score 1):

Download [**Windows Virtual PC**](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/). 
And test you application in it.
 You can customize your configuration, everything like disk storage, ram memory etc. 
Good application for application developers to test in different environments.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could create a virtual machine on your computer. You could then vary how much RAM & processing power it has access to. You could boot this machine of a USB drive if you wanted to simulate a slower drive.